Add json to json
I'm trying to update my firewall and it needs JSON through the API. Now it seems that to create a new rule, I have to read all previous rules, add the new rule and send the complete set back.
This is what I get back:
{
  "status": "REALIZED",
  "systemRules": null,
  "userDefinedRules": [
    {
      "id": "bf9600d2-333a-45a0-adc0-113f86a9682d",
      "name": "Test3625",
      "description": null,
      "sourceFirewallGroups": null,
      "destinationFirewallGroups": null,
    },
    {
      "id": "35fd3-333a-45a0-adc0-113f86a9682d",
      "name": "Test22984",
      "description": null,
      "sourceFirewa llGroups": null,
      "destinationFirewallGroups": null,
    }
  ],
  "defaultRules": [
    {
      "id": "default_ru le",
      "name": "default_rule",
      "description": "default rule",
      "sourceFirewallGroups": null,
      "destinationFirewallGroups": null,
    }
  ]
}

I then convert it:
$FWRules = $JSON | ConvertFrom-JSON

Now I want to add to userdefinedrules:
    {
      "id": "9999-333a-45a0-adc0-113f86a9682d",
      "name": "Test7777",
      "description": null,
      "sourceFirewa llGroups": null,
      "destinationFirewallGroups": null,
    }

$newrule = $newjson | convertfrom-json

According to the examples I find, I should use add-member. But then I have to use the -name property and I don't understand in my situation how to address that, as I don't have any names.

No need for Add-Member, just $FWRules.userDefinedRules = @($FWRules.userDefinedRules; $newRule)

or just $FWRules.userDefinedRules += $newrule if userDefinedRules is always a json array

Thanks. This works for the simple example, but not for the real case :-) :-) I have to analyse that very carefully.

If you want to answer to a different question then I suggest asking that question :)

No I meant I tried to make the question simple instead of 40 lines of json. Might have made it a little too simple. But think I'll manage now :-)
